# What's the role of "* *" in this Perl script?

Tags: perl

I have this shell script:

```sh
eval{print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}
```

and more variants:

```
@${print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}
$${print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}
do{print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}
$#{print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}
```

What does `* *` do? (It also works if I change `* *` to `& &`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `*` of each pair is multiplication; the second is a glob dereference.  So nothing very useful.

With `& &` the first is bitwise and and the second is a subroutine dereference (and call).  I don't know why using the canonical true value (returned by print) as a code ref and calling it doesn't error; I would have expected `&{!0}` to error like `&{"1"}` does with `Undefined subroutine &main::1`; instead it seems to be a no-op.

Comment: IIRC `&{!0}` doing nothing is an implementation detail (possibly related to `Foo::Bar->import` never being an error, even if there is no import method) leaking through.